# How to avoid the motorway road in Here map API query

Tags: here-api

I want to avoid the motorway road when calculate the route between the start and destination

```
https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&motorway:-1&origin=52.120066,11.570918&destination=52.282376,6.687846&return=travelsummary,polyline&apikey=<key>
```

But above query doesn't work, it not avoid the motorway

Refer documents:https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-routing-mode.html

And I already check their is possibility of the route, to avoid the motorway.

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/'52.120066,11.570918'/'52.282376,6.687846'/@52.3407684,7.9868359,8z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m12!4m11!1m3!2m2!1d11.570918!2d52.120066!1m3!2m2!1d6.687846!2d52.282376!2m1!1b1!3e0

Comment: Can you please share link to documentation where you found `motorway:-1` parameter?

Comment: @Tomas Please refer the RouteFeatureWeightType section in below link

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/dev_guide/topics/resource-param-type-routing-mode.html#type-route-feature

Comment: O.K. so it just got mixed, as this documentation is for routing v7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [Routing v8 documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/api-reference-swagger.html) the proper parameter to avoid all highways is `avoid[features]=controlledAccessHighway` instead of `motorway:-1`

`https://router.hereapi.com/v8/routes?transportMode=car&avoid[features]=controlledAccessHighway&origin=52.120066,11.570918&destination=52.282376,6.687846&return=travelsummary,polyline&apikey=..`

**Note**: probably better value to use is `tollRoad` as it allows highways without tolls (e.g. in Germany)